# Unable to start debugging : The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, gdb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently started working on vscode. I wanted to debug my C code. But the moment I am launching the debugger getting Error : Unable to start debugging. The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid.

I have my gdb installed on wsl . It's path is /usr/bin/gdb. I have copied same path to launch.json in miDebuggerPath.

Here is my launch.json :

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [


    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/main",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

It should not throw the error and I should able to launch my debugger.

Comment: Is VSCode launched in WSL or in Windows?

Comment: Ever got it working?

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw `Missing the mingw-w64-gdb package is one cause of the "The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid." message upon attempted compilation if your PATH is correct.`

Answer (score 76):

So this happened to me on WSL-Ubuntu. In my case gdb was broken because of unmet dependencies. Took a while to fix but once I reinstalled gdb properly in my WSL-Ubuntu, I finally got it working.

Installing gdb can be done on shell as

```
sudo apt-get install gdb
```

There can be multiple reasons why it could end up as broken, but once you fix gdb, vscode-debugging should be running. At the very least, you won't see that error popping.

Comment: For Arch-based Linux users:
`sudo pacman -S gdb`
https://archlinux.org/packages/extra/x86_64/gdb/

Comment: This answer worked for me. I had a new WSL installation, so before trying the suggested command, my gdb was in /usr/share/gdb and even when I put this path in my lauch.json, it still did not work. When I installed gdb as per the suggested command, everything worked as expected (and gdb was installed in /usr/bin/gdb)

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, my solution was:

**1. Change this section in launch.json**

```
"miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb",
```

for:

```
"miDebuggerPath": "C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe",
```

**2. Do you need to install in your PC  MinGW, this is the link:**

https://osdn.net/projects/mingw/downloads/68260/mingw-get-setup.exe/

**3. Next, open the MinGW then you install in the URL "C:/MinGW/bin" the gdb (select)**

```
mingw32-gdb-bin
```

**4. Enjoy the vs-code**

Comment: The description is actually saying it's under wsl, not mingw

Comment: IT worked for me just by changing to `C:/MinGW/bin/gdb.exe`. Ty

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best way to do it, since you are referencing a file stored on your Windows system from the linux subsystem. Ideally, those two remain as separate as possible.

Answer (score 4):

it should be

```
"miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdbus",
```

Comment: Why? gdbus doesn't appear to have anything to do with gdb. Also, I get the error `Unknown command '--interpreter=mi'`

Answer (score 3):

If you're running under WSL, you should check where `gdb` is in your current distro to set your "miDebuggerPath" using

```
whereis gdb
```

in my case it was in

```
/usr/bin/gdb
```

but it could be somewhere else, that depends on what Linux distribution are you using with WSL

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar problem, running on linux.
**Installing gdb fixed it.**

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this:

```sh
sudo apt install binfmt-support
```

I am using VcXsrv, and this fixed all my installation problems, including chrome and GNU C++.

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar problem ,this fixed. WINDOWS 10

QUICK ANSWER : try
1)**C:\your compiler\bin\gdb.exe** (paste your compiler path )
or
2)**C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\gdb32.exe** for 32 bit compiler .(in my case)

(i tried to use opengl GLFW glad with 32bit tdm-gcc c++ compiler , i used a repo from [OpenGL C++ template by vkphillia](https://github.com/vkphillia/opengl-cpp-template)

but when i tried to run it in vs code using "run without debugging " option ,it showed the error "Unable to start debugging : The value of miDebuggerPath is invalid",

i copied  my tdm_gcc compiler's bin path in midebugger path and it was like this ,
**C:\TDM-GCC-32\bin\gdb.exe** , but it did not remove the error then i checked for the gdb.exe application in my tdm gcc compiler bin where i noticed that there was no gdb.exe but a **gdb32.exe** file